# Memory Manipulation in Java on linux

Tags: java, memory

I'd like to get into manipulating the memory of another program with java. I'm most familiar with java. I'd say i'm intermediate with it.
If there is any sort of memory manipulation with documentation that functions under linux that'd be greatly appreciated if someone could point me to it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If by manipulating you mean modifying values in memory allocated to a non JVM process, Java is the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: What languages would be more suited for the task at hand? I suppose I'm open to trying out new languages.